# Evitar barra invertida en .split jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, split, ascii, stack

*Tengo la siguiente cadena:*

```
var cadena = "cadena1\cadena2";
```

necesito separar la cadena en dos palabras "cadena1" y "cadena2".

he intentado con una barra invertida:

- `console.log(cadena.split("\\")()[0]);`
- `console.log(cadena.split("\\")()[1]);`

con dos barras invertidas:

- `console.log(cadena.split("\\\\")()[0]);`
- `console.log(cadena.split("\\\\")()[1]);`

y con código ascii:

- `console.log(cadena.split(String.fromCharCode(92))[0]);`
- `console.log(cadena.split(String.fromCharCode(92))[1]);`

**pero no funciona ninguna de las opciones.**

https://jsfiddle.net/B3RS3RK3R/k2ygcuhf/2/

Answer (score 3):

La diagonal invertida es un caracter de escape y debe escaparse a sí mismo para poder incluirlo en una cadena directamente.

Cuando proviene de otra fuente, como el valor de un input o respuesta de una llamada AJAX (en teoría) ya viene escapado y puedes usarlo sin problemas.

Una breve referencia de acerca de caracteres que deben ser "escapados": https://tutobasico.com/escape-javascript/

```js
// Cuando lo usas en una cadena debes escaparlo:
var cadena = "cadena1\cadena2"; // Sin escapar no funciona
console.log(cadena.split('\\')); // También aquí debes escaparlo

cadena = "cadena1\\cadena2"; // Escapado funciona
console.log(cadena.split('\\'));

document.querySelector('#separar').addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Ya viene listo
    let valor = document.querySelector('#texto').value;
    console.log(valor.split('\\'));
});
```

```html
<input id="texto" value="cadena1\cadena2">
<button id="separar">Separar</button>
```