# ¿Cómo debo manipular "\" en un String en Java?

Tags: java, string, split

¿Cómo se puede crear un String de esta forma: `String s = "\";` ?

Se recibe cómo Input un String como este:

```java
 String t = "C:\Carpeta 1\Carpeta 2\Un Archivo.text";
```

Y se quiere imprimir en consola:

```
C:\\Carpeta 1\\Carpeta 2\\Un Archivo.text
```

Comment: es un caracter especial por lo cual debes colocar dos ``"\\"`

Comment: @JackNavaRow Si ya sé qué es un carácter especial, pero ponte que que no eres tú quien lo pones, sino que lees una línea de un fichero, y ese fichero contiene ese carácter.

Comment: si lo coloca el fichero es porque tiene un caracter especial asi que no es de preocupar

Comment: @JackNavaRow No sé si me explico bien, no es que lo ponga un archivo, sino recibes como input un String  que tiene ese carácter, y no tiene para nada la intención de usarse cómo carácter especial.

Comment: En Javascript y PHP funciona como en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/375212/evitar-barra-invertida-en-split-jquery/375217#375217) y casi tengo la certeza de que en Java es igual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que quieres reemplazar cada ocurrencia de `\` con `\\` para que se imprima con las dos \, es muy simple.

```
String r = t.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Espero que usar unicode sirva ya que el simbolo ( \ ) no se puede utilizar por que ya se ocupa con (\n) salto de linea, (\t) tabulacion etc.**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myUnicodeSymbol = "\u005c\";
    System.out.println(myUnicodeSymbol);
}
```