# Como reemplazar este caracter "\" en javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Buen dia a todos,

Estoy tratando de hacer string.replace en javascript, quiero cambiar este caracter \ por este /
Intente con `replace(/\/g, "/")` y `replace(/"\"/g,"/")` pero no funcionaron jeje, saben si es un codigo en especifico para ese caracter?

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Esto ya se pregunto [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/375212/54039)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tiene una entidad específica que puedes reemplazar con una expresión regular, haciendo que la expresión regular tome `\` como un signo y reemplazarlo

Esta expresión regular bastará

```
/\\/g
```

En Javascript:

```
str.replace(/\\/g ,"/");
```

Comment: Funciono, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas expresiones regulares para esta tarea, puedes valerte de la función [`replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) y pasar directamente el caracter `\`. Mira este ejemplo:

```js
var s = "hola \\mundo\\ esto es\\ una prueba";

console.log(s.replaceAll("\\" ,"/"));
```

Si te preguntas por qué en el código aparece `\\` y no solo `\`, te explico:

El propio caracter `\` sirve para iniciar secuencias de escape, que se utilizan para incluir caracteres unicode o caracteres no imprimibles (como el salto de línea `\n` o el tabulador `\t`). Por ello, cada vez que quiero incluir un caracter `\`, debo hacerlo con una doble diagonal `\\`, que es la secuencia de escape que corresponde a un único `\`.